# How to put CSS 3d hover effect?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, user-interface

```
             <div class="com-wrapper">
              <div class="front">
               <div class="com-icon">
                 <img src="images/household.png" alt="laptop logo">
               </div>
               <div class="com-text">
                 <p>Household</p>
               </div>
              </div>
               <div class="description">
                  <ul>
                    <li>Plumber and Electrician</li>
                    <li>Cleaning Service</li>
                    <li>Carpentry</li>
                    <li>Agriculture</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
             </div>
```

I want to keep the description div hidden at first and only reveal it when hovered on front div . How do I do it with CSS3 3D hover or any hover effect.
I've tried and failed.

Answer (score -1):

`.className` and add `:hover`

Example:

```
.myDiscriptionClass:hover {
   display: block; }
```

You can make a 3D effect using shadow effects.